# Edit video metadata using clickntap api error

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm trying to edit the metadata for the video which i have uploaded and I have been getting error status 400 in the response from the vimeo server. `I'm using ClicknTap api for java`.
The parameters are all correct as from my perspective and code is attached below.

```
Vimeo vimeo = new Vimeo("c8a84c2f936c934a4735bc22bdcd5fa0");
String name = "Demo1";
String desc = "Description here";
String license = ""; 
String privacyView = "disable"; // see Vimeo API Documentation
String privacyEmbed = "whitelist";
boolean reviewLink = false;
 VimeoResponse respon=vimeo.updateVideoMetadata(videoEndPoint,name,desc,license,privacyView, privacyEmbed, reviewLink);
System.out.println(respon);
```

The output is as shown below:
HTTP Status Code: 
400

```
Json:
   {
    "developer_message": "The parameters passed to this API endpoint did not pass Vimeo's validation. Please check the invalid_parameters list for more information",
    "link": null,
    "error_code": 2204,
    "error": "You have provided an invalid parameter. Please contact developer of this application.",
    "invalid_parameters": [{
    "field": "privacy.view",
    "developer_message": "The parameters passed to this API endpoint did not pass Vimeo's validation. Please check the invalid_parameters list for more information",
    "error_code": 2204,
    "error": "You have provided an invalid parameter. Please contact developer of this application."
    }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out my mistake. I changed privacyView and privacyEmbed values to ***nobody*** and ***private*** respectively and the code worked. The clean code is as follows.

```
        String name = "Demo1";
        String desc = "Description here";
        String license = null;
        String privacyView = "nobody";
        String privacyEmbed = "private";
        boolean reviewLink = false;
        VimeoResponse respon = vimeo.updateVideoMetadata(videoEndPoint,
                    name, desc, license, privacyView, privacyEmbed, reviewLink);
```

Hope this would be helpful for someone in future.